# django contact form receiving email for free

Tags: python, django

I just finished setting up a contact form thanks to some [tutorial](https://hellowebapp.com/news/tutorial-setting-up-a-contact-form-with-django/), but on the tutorial I took it says I have to setup sendgrid or some other service to get the reply. but thing is they aren't free.

Is there a way to get the emails for free?

```
def contact(request):

    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name','')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email','')
            form_content = request.POST.get('content','')
            template=get_template('contact_template.txt')
            context = Context({
                'contact_name':contact_name,
                'contact_email':contact_email,
                'form_content':form_content,
                })
            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "New Contact form submisssion",
                content,
                "your website"+'',
                ['ebagu.net@gmail.com'],
                headers = {'Reply-To':contact_email})
            email.send()
            return redirect('contact')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form':form_class,
        })
```

I have this in txt file, and this is what I get in email

```
Contact Name:


Email:


Content:
```

Comment: You can try services like mailgun. They give you 12k emails/month for free

Comment: @v1k45 yeah but do I have to pay?is there a way to do it for free?do all websites use services like this?

Comment: nope, you don't have to pay anything if you send less then 12k emails/month. mailgun is used by github and other big sites :)

Comment: @v1k45 wait I don't need the service to send email, I just want to be able to receive messages from my users on my contact us page. I want to receive those messages on my gmail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you're asking about email services, they have nothing to do with your question. Your email is blank because you don't seem to have any variable placeholders in your template. Add `{{ contact_name }}` etc to fill in the data, just as you would with an HTML template.